# Task 'sass' is not in your gulpfile

Tags: gulp, frontend, gulp-sass

I've installed gulp and gulp-sass using npm.

Following the examples on github for gulp and gulp-sass I've created this simple gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp') ;
var sass = require('gulp-sass') ;

gulp.task('default', function() {

    gulp.task('sass', function () {
        gulp.src('./sass/**/*.scss')
            .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
    });

    gulp.task('sass:watch', function () {
        gulp.watch('./sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
    });

}) ;
```

If I run 'gulp' then nothing really happens - as expected. I get back

```
[00:20:20] Using gulpfile ~/wa/myproj/gulpfile.js
[00:20:20] Starting 'default'...
[00:20:20] Finished 'default' after 64 μs
```

That's all fine and dandy.

However, when I run 'gulp sass' I get back this:

```
[00:21:38] Using gulpfile ~/wa/myproj/gulpfile.js
[00:21:38] Task 'sass' is not in your gulpfile
[00:21:38] Please check the documentation for proper gulpfile formatting
```

I've clearly got a taks defined for 'sass'. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

It probably didn't call because it was the function was inside default, and also default needs to call the other functions, after defining it outside default.

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
gulp.task('sass', function(){
    gulp.src('./sass/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});
gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch('./sass/**/*.scss',['sass']);
});
gulp.task('default', ['sass','watch']);
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

The 'sass' task was wrapped inside the 'default' task.

This works:

```
var gulp = require('gulp') ;
var sass = require('gulp-sass') ;

gulp.task('default', function() {

}) ;

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    gulp.src('./sass/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});

gulp.task('sass:watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('./sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue **"Task 'sass' is not in your gulpfile"** when I use gulp scss command.

But when my friend ran **gulp css** command in command prompt, it worked properly by updating the CSS file. Please look at the below image, I hope this might help you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function(){
    gulp.src('./scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch('./scss/**/*.scss',['sass']);
});
```

This works for me. Try it out. But I have to say My SASS folder's name is 'scss'. I changed the name and deleted the default task.